# Using the Django auth model for things other than permissions

Tags: django, django-authentication

Is it appropriate to use the Django auth model groups for something other than permission management? I am just learning Django, and am trying to make a site that manages groups of users. As an example, think of a site for managing email groups or local community charities or fan clubs or some such. I want to use the groups for managing things like sending an email to everyone in the group, or organizing an event and dividing the preparations between the group or any number of other things that are not permission related. Is this an appropriate use of the auth model, or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to use your groups to handle permissions, you'd better create a separate model, just because you'll hardly benefit of using the stock model (which is just [a permissions container](https://github.com/django/django/blob/53ccffdb8c8e47a4d4304df453d8c79a9be295ab/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L99)). And customization is much, much easier when you have a separate model. You could start with just:

```
class EmailGroup(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='email_groups')
```

and extend it to your needs.

But there's nothing *wrong* in using `contrib.auth` models in a different way. Django is a framework, not a CMS, so you're free to use it as you want.